# Parsing XML too slow?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I read similar questios, but i don't understand how i can get xml data from an url faster?

Why this code runs so slow:

```
while($id = $getFix->fetch()){ 
    $odds=$this->soccer->GetAllOddsByFixtureMatchId(array("fixtureMatch_Id"=>$id['Id']));
    }

    if(!empty($odds)){
       $stmt = $this->PDO->prepare("CALL insupd_Odds(:fixturematchid, :bookmaker, :updatedDate, :type,:homeodds, :drawodds, :awayodds, :handicap)");
    foreach($odds as $key=>$value){
       $stmt->bindParam(':fixturematchid',$value->FixtureMatch_Id);
       $stmt->bindParam(':bookmaker',$value->Bookmaker);    
       $stmt->bindParam(':updatedDate',$value->UpdatedDate);
       $stmt->bindParam(':type',$value->Type);
       $stmt->bindParam(':homeodds',$value->HomeOdds);
       $stmt->bindParam(':drawodds',$value->DrawOdds);
       $stmt->bindParam(':awayodds',$value->AwayOdds);
       $stmt->bindParam(':handicap',$value->Handicap);
       $stmt->execute();
    }
    }
```

I need to list all odds by fixture id which is stored in my database, so i need to call all ids from database and send that id's to xml feeder who returns me all odds from fixtures and then i store it into database... 
It s running more than 300 seconds and then execute...

This is important parser code:

```
public function __call($name,$params){
    $data=$this->request($this->buildUrl($name,$params));
    if(false===($xml = simplexml_load_string($data))) throw new XMLSoccerException("Invalid XML");
    if(strstr($xml[0],"To avoid misuse of the service")){
        switch($name){
            case "GetLiveScore":
            case "GetLiveScoreByLeague":
            case "GetOddsByFixtureMatchID":
            case "GetHistoricMatchesByLeagueAndSeason":
            case "GetAllTeams":
            case "GetAllTeamsByLeagueAndSeason":
                throw new XMLSoccerException($xml[0],constant("self::TIMEOUT_".$name));
            default:
                throw new XMLSoccerException($xml[0],self::TIMEOUT_Others);
        }
    }
    return $xml;
}
```

I know that is probably main problem in xml checking id's, but it is only way that i can to get odds by fixture, also i can to use by leagues, but it is same...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the following...

```
while($id = $getFix->fetch())
{ 
  $odds=$this->soccer->GetAllOddsByFixtureMatchId(array("fixtureMatch_Id"=>$id['Id']));
}
```

It appears you may be querying remotely for a whole bunch of odds but storing them all in the same variable.  When you get out of the loop you have the last set of odds collected available for insert/update or other processing.

However, it would be really nice to have a bit more description about what you are doing, what the different methods are expected to do and return, and so on.

Again, guessing, but perhaps you have a date of last update on your records? If so, and you rely on it, then the first call might return all records, then the next call might return all but one record (since it looks like only the last one fetched was processed) and so on.  That's a lot of fetch requests to the external site -- which could explain a very long execution time.

If I'm barking up the wrong tree please supply additional details and I'll try to provide a better diagnosis.

Comment: What is better way to store that amount of data? Maybe in some list or array? I am getting very much data, leagues, teams, fixtures, live fixtures, historic matches(this is greates table with maybe more than million rows),
scorers, players, standings etc.. I am getting all of that data from www.xmlsoccer.com/FootballData.asmx and store it my database using pdo, transactions and procedures... I want to store all odds in next 30 days, and i need to send every id of fixture what i want to get, if u understand me...

Comment: Okay, how many future games do you generally have in your database that require fetching in order to get the latest odds?  How many are you loading before doing the first database update?